# Disable 'Create a mailing-list' option

Tags: server

How to disable "create a new mailing list" option showing up on admin page for public.

Example:
http://mm.gnu.org.in/cgi-bin/mailman/admin

Answer (score 2):

You can change `/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admin.py`. Remember to back it up!

Original:

```
    creatorurl = Utils.ScriptURL('create')
    mailman_owner = Utils.get_site_email()
    extra = msg and _('right ') or ''
    welcome.extend([
        _('''To visit the administrators configuration page for an
        unadvertised list, open a URL similar to this one, but with a '/' and
        the %(extra)slist name appended.  If you have the proper authority,
        you can also <a href="%(creatorurl)s">create a new mailing list</a>.

        <p>General list information can be found at '''),
        Link(Utils.ScriptURL('listinfo'),
             _('the mailing list overview page')),
        '.',
        _('<p>(Send questions and comments to '),
        Link('mailto:%s' % mailman_owner, mailman_owner),
        '.)<p>',
        ])
```

Version without create link:

```
    creatorurl = Utils.ScriptURL('create')
    mailman_owner = Utils.get_site_email()
    extra = msg and _('right ') or ''
    welcome.extend([
        _('''To visit the administrators configuration page for an
        unadvertised list, open a URL similar to this one, but with a '/' and
        the %(extra)slist name appended.

        <p>General list information can be found at '''),
        Link(Utils.ScriptURL('listinfo'),
             _('the mailing list overview page')),
        '.',
        _('<p>(Send questions and comments to '),
        Link('mailto:%s' % mailman_owner, mailman_owner),
        '.)<p>',
        ])
```

Remember that this doesn't disable the creation of new lists, but just hide the link! So you still have to have a good list creation password!

Answer (score 2):

This is dredging up a very old thread, but this is how I achieved it, that doesn't involve hacking python. I simply redirect the URL in the apache config.

On Ubuntu, it's `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mailman.conf`. Add this line:

```
Redirect /mailman/create /mailman/admin
```

And graceful Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful
```

Any attempt to load http://example.com/mailman/create will just redirect to http://example.com/mailman/admin .

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the link and change the /var/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/listinfo.py not the admin.py .  and add (at) like below  , 
   mailman_owner = Utils.get_site_email()
   welcome.extend([
        _('''To visit the administrators configuration page for an
        unadvertised list, open a URL similar to this one, but with a '/' and
        the %(extra)slist name appended.

```
    <p>General list information can be found at '''),
    Link(Utils.ScriptURL('listinfo'),
         _('the mailing list overview page')),
    '.',
    _('<p>(Send questions and comments to '),
    ('mailman (at) mail.domain.com'),
    '.)<p>',
    ])
```

And with this in first page of mailman when we see all lists not link to mail . is most effective if we think about spammers .

Answer (score 0):

You could make apache password protect the create script - that way your admins can still use it (all be it with separate credentials).

This is what mailman put in my apache config file:

```
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /path/to/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/path/to/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I added this:

```
    # For some reason, +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch causes apache to not apply auth
    <Directory "/path/to/cgi-bin/mailman/">
            Options -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/path/to/cgi-bin/mailman/create">
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Authentication required"
            AuthUserFile "/path/to/mailmanusers"
            Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

having created the AuthUserFile with one user in it with:

```
htpasswd -c /path/to/mailmanusers myusername
```